# How to achieve the following in extjs

Tags: extjs, layout, header, panel

```
--Title-------------------------------
|                                     |
|                                     |
|            <Content>                |
|                                     |
|_____________________________________|
```

How to achieve the above panel in extjs?

Edit: 
It should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    bodyPadding: 5,
    layout : {
            align : 'center',
            pack : 'center',
            type : 'vbox'
    },
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Title',
    items: [{
        Your ExtJs Content
    }]
});
```

I think it's not really hard to find this answer via Google ...

Edit : link to JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tub2506d/1/

Comment: Simply replace   "Ext.panel.Panel" by "Ext.form.FieldSet"  http://jsfiddle.net/hy7z2q3q/

Answer (score 2):

ExtJs item fieldset is just what you are looking for ;)

Comment: Try adding a bit more explanation and maybe code to help OP fully understand your solution.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I was looking for. the other answer has a fiddle for the same